# IIS 8 Url rewrite rule negate not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I tried to allow specific IPs which can request my endpoint.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect for Api/Login" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="api/login" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="192.168.0.10" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="192.168.0.11" negate="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="You shaw not pass!" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When I request from this IP response is 403 :(

Answer (score 0):

According to your url rewrite codes, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I suggest you could try to check REMOTE_ADDR in your codes to make sure the IP address is the '192.168.0.10'.

My test url rewrite rule as below:

```
            <rule name="TestRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="172.17.16.53" negate="true" />

                     <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="172.17.16.54" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="You shaw not pass!" />
            </rule>
```

The 172.17.16.53 remote computer access the server network details:

[image]

If I access from another computesr, it wil throw the 403 error.

[image]